# Wrap php in shortcode

Tags: shortcode

I'm using a plugin that will display content based on user location, and I'm trying to add it to a facebook widget code. The plugin is using a shortcode to wrap content that will be displayed, and here is what I have so far. I know I'm doing something wrong, and would really appreciate it if you can point me to the right direction.

```
if (($user_id) and ($app_id) and ($secret_code)){
    $user_data = get_option('wt_recent_fb_posts_user');

    echo do_shortcode ('[wpgc_is_city city="Morrisville"]');

    if ((!$user_data) OR ($user_data[0]->id !== $user_id)){
        $user_data = $this -> fetch_userdata($user_id);             
    }               

    $fb_posts = get_transient('wt_recent_fb_posts');                
    if (!$fb_posts){ //no messages, fetch from facebook             
        $fb_posts = $this->fetch_fbposts($user_id, $post_count, $app_id, $secret_code);             
    } else {
        $fb_posts = get_transient( 'wt_recent_fb_posts' );                  
    }

    if(isset($user_data[0]->name)){
        echo "<div class='user'><h3><a href='".$user_data[0]->url."' target='_blank'>".$user_data[0]->name."</a></h3></div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='user'>Facebook</div>";
    }

    echo "<div class='fb-posts-list'><ul class='slides'>";

    foreach ($fb_posts as $fb_post) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<div class='message'>".$fb_post->message."</div>";
        $created_time = $fb_post->created_time;
        $time_ago = sprintf(__('%s ago', 'wellthemes'), human_time_diff(strtotime($created_time))); 
        echo "<div class='time'>".$time_ago."</div>";                                   
        echo "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul></div><div class='fb-posts-nav'></div>"; 
    echo do_shortcode('[/wpgc_is_city]');
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but you haven't said what the problem is? What are you asking? What is it supposed to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: Sorry I forgot.. You will see that I added `echo do_shortcode ('[wpgc_is_city city="Morrisville"]');` and `echo do_shortcode('[/wpgc_is_city]');` but the content is still showing even if I'm not from that city

Comment: Oooh that's bad, your shortcode string should be a shortcode, not a fragment of a shortcode, do_shortcode is not psychic. Imagine, some other plugin could put a '[/yourshortcodehere]' at the very end of the page, and ruin everything if you could do that!

Answer (score 1):

[From Codex Shortcode Examples](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode#Examples)

> // In case there is opening and closing shortcode.
>   echo do_shortcode('[iscorrect]'.$text_to_be_wrapped_in_shortcode.'[/iscorrect]');

Basically, you can't use `do_shortcode()` two separate times for what is one shortcode consisting of a pair of tags.

In your code you need to save your output to variables instead of using `echo`. Then at the end wrap it in the shortcode like the example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the responses.. I actually drop the [shortcode] stuff and just use the function of the shortcode it self.

something like this..

```
$location = shortcode_city($atts, $content='');
if ($user_loc1 == $location){
// Code here
}
```

Thanks again guys!